# Is there anyway to have C# Regex.Matches return all the valid entries?

Tags: c#, regex

I need to find all the occurrences of `_X_` in a string (where X is any upper case English letter, that is A-Z

Consider this string: `"_A_B_C_D_"`

The occurrences I am looking for are
`_A_`
`_B_`
`_C_`
`_D_`

Using C# Regex.Matches:

```
var input = "_A_B_C_D_";
var pattern = "_[A-Z]_";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
```

The result is
`_A_`
`_C_`

so, obviously my pattern is wrong.

What is the correct pattern?

Update: Thanks folks. This works. `(?=(_[A-Z]_))`

Comment: You can use lookaround, although the matches won't include the underscores https://regex101.com/r/7NEEun/1

Comment: I tried this `var pattern = "(?<=_)[A-Z](?=_)";` but I am getting A B C D. you can add _ before and after

Comment: This works: `(?=(_[A-Z]_))`